# Select minimum key value pair in List<Dictionary<string,string>> where dictionary value is a date as string

Tags: c#, datetime, dictionary

So I have a

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>>
```

gotten from using

```
var differences = activeCalls.Where(l1 => !tempActiveCalls.Any(l2 => l1 == l2));
```

that holds an id as the key and a date formatted as

```
DateTime.ToString("s")
```

What I would like is to get the key value pair that has the earliest date. 
Right now I am using

```
List<Dictionary<string, DateTime>> minDate = new List<Dictionary<string, DateTime>>();
//convert strings to dates
foreach(var dictionary in differences)
{
    foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
    {
        minDate.Add(new Dictionary<string, DateTime>()
        {
            {kvp.Key, DateTime.ParseExact(kvp.Value,"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss",null) }
        });
    }
}
```

to convert the strings into datetime format but am stuck on how to select the minimum key/value pair based on date. I also don't think this is the simplest method at all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not following. You want 1 instance of a key value pair in any one of your dictionaries where that key has the smallest value across all other keys across all dictionaries?

Comment: @Igor Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, order it by key and get the first element. This works because of the way the key is structured in your dictionary instances, `DateTime.ToString("s")` produces a sortable date time string (its ISO notation), there is no need to convert it to a `DateTime` type. The `SelectMany` will flatten the dictionary instances into a single collection. Using `OrderBy` will order ascending (earliest to latest).

```
var result = differences.SelectMany(y => y).OrderBy(x => x.Key).First();
```

*You will need to include `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file.*

Comment: Wow that is overly simple compared to my messed up method! I should have taken a clue from the fact that ToString("s") is called the sortable format......thanks!